# Windows Universal App - Javascript - File IO - Crash if file already exist

Tags: javascript, file-io, win-universal-app

I am doing the following:

```
var content = "XYZ - stuff to write to file";
Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.createFileAsync("myfile.txt").done(
    function (newFile) {
        if (newFile) {
            // Prevent updates to the remote version of the file until we finish making changes and call CompleteUpdatesAsync.
            Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.deferUpdates(newFile);
            // write to file
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(newFile, content).done(function () {
            // Let Windows know that we're finished changing the file so the other app can update the remote version of the file.
            // Completing updates may require Windows to ask for user input.
            Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.completeUpdatesAsync(newFile).done(function (updateStatus) {
                if (updateStatus === Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.complete) {
                    //WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + newFile.name + " was saved.", "sample", "status");
                } else {
                    //WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + newFile.name + " couldn't be saved.", "sample", "status");
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        // Could not access the new file
    }
        }
    );
```

However, if the file already exists it crashes saying the file already exists.

How do I check to see if the file already exists and only do the create if it is not there?

Basically I know I want to write to (not append) to `myfile.txt`. So I need to get `newFile` whether it is already existing or not so I can use writeTextAsync on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I check to see if the file already exists and only do the create if it is not there?

If there is an existing file in the current folder that already has the specified desiredName, the specified [`CreationCollisionOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption) determines how Windows responds to the conflict. The enum value can be `FailIfExists`, `GenerateUniqueName`, `OpenIfExists` or `ReplaceExisting`.

Since you are accessing the [`DownloadsFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder), apps can't access files in the Downloads folder that they didn't create. More details about file access permission please reference [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3a404cc0-a997-45c8-b2e8-44745539759d). So you can only set the `CreationCollisionOption` to `FailIfExists` or `GenerateUniqueName`.

According to your description, you need a new file to write text, so you can set the option to `GenerateUniqueName` which will generate a new file with unique name, for example, "myfile(2).txt". Code as follows:

```
 Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.createFileAsync("myfile.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName).done(
     function (newFile) {...  });
```

More details please reference the scenario 1 of the [file access official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess).

If you just want to use the desired file name , not to generate a new one, you may add the file to the [`FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_FutureAccessList)  and then access it later.  Pay attention that the existing file must be created by same user so that you can delete and re-create a new one later. The sample code about this you can reference the scenario 7 of the official sample.